# NGINX Forward HTTPS from any domain to specific URL

Tags: nginx

I am implementing an internal DNS server for block specific DNS requests to malicious websites, using a DNSRBL list against bind9. Whenever there's a match, the DNS server responds with the IP of an internal NGINX server that serves a block page.

Example, when the internal client requests http://www.badsite.com/ the DNS server responds with 192.168.0.100 as an example, which is the IP of the NGINX server. Then NGINX uses a 301 to forward the request to an HTTPS site which serves the block page message to the end user.

That works well using a simple NGINX config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://block.xyz.com;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name block.xyz.com;    
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/block.xyz.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/block.xyz.com/privkey.pem;    
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }    
}
```

The issue I'm having is when the client requests an HTTPS site, i.e.:https://www.badsite.com/ . I would like to forward any incoming SSL/443 requests to https://block.xyz.com. I've tried adding the following directive:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        server_name _;    
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/block.xyz.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/block.xyz.com/privkey.pem;
        return 301 https://block.xyz.com;
}
```

And I get the typical SSL error saying the certificate doesn't match the domain: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, which is understandable. The same thing happens when I change the directive from return to rewrite:

```
...
rewrite ^ https://block.xyz.com;
....
```

How would I go about adding a directive in NGINX to accomplish this? This guide (https://sweetcode.io/ad-blocking-with-local-dns-servers-and-nginx/) provided me a way to do the http side for implementing something similar for Ad Blocking, but doesn't speak to https requests.

Any clues?

Comment: `Pihole` might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your `server` block try adding:

```
        if ($host != "block.xyz.com") {
           rewrite ^/(.*) https://block.xyz.com/$1 permanent;
        }
```

Comment: Tried that, but that didn't work either. Still getting the SSL Error rather than rewriting or forwarding to https://block.xyz.com

Comment: There are a few points that might possibly help in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152552/nginx-websockets-ssl-not-working-neterr-cert-common-name-invalid).